# has_many through associations find count of physician.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to get the count(physician.id) but I'm getting errors in rails.

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :appointments
 has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :physician
 belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :appointments
 has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

and what I'm doing here is:

```
patients_count = Patient.joins(:physicians).includes(:physicians).select('count(physician.id) as count').group('patients.id').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
```

I'm getting this error, `"PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: ...CT COUNT(DISTINCT count(physician.id) as count)"`

not sure if pagination is causing this issue, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

While using an attribute on a model it should be in the plural for in query
i.e `physicians.id` instead of `physician.id`

```
patients_count = Patient.joins(:physicians)
                            #.includes(:physicians)
                            .group('patients.id')
                            .select("count(physicians.id) as count")
                            .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
```

Comment: thank you but im still getting this error `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(count(physicians.id)) AS count_count`

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelling error in your query. Also, I think we don't need `includes` in this case. You're forcing to join twice

```
patients_count = Patient.joins(:physicians).select('count(physicians.id) as count').group('patients.id').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
```

Comment: thanks, still getting the same error `PG::GroupingError: ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(count(physicians.id)) AS count_count`

Comment: Hi, I tested with `rails 5.2.3`, gem `pg 1.1.4`, `PostgreSQL 10`, ` will_paginate (3.1.7)` and it works. Are you sure you are applying correct SQL query? I have no idea why u generated `SELECT COUNT(count(pysicians.id))`, duplicated `COUNT` and `count`

Comment: this is really weird, I have the same exact versions, I have this also `render json: patient, meta: pagination(patient), adapter: :json`